# What is the correct JSON format to report "DateTime" property to IoT Central?

Tags: azure-iot-central

**Question 1:**
As titled. I was able to report `Location` property using `Device Property` library in the `Property` tab in Azure IoT Central, but cannot find the correct json format to report a `DateTime` property.

Here a copy of device twin I got back from IoT Central when I start my application:

```
"reported": {
  "location": {
    "lon": 120.567238,
    "lat": 36.044977
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "value": "2018-09-25T09:21:56Z"
  }
}
```

**Question 2:**
Since I mentioned the `Location` property, is it also possible to report a `Location` without it being part of the `Device Property` library (as shown in the sample device templates)? Since a `Location` library already exist, it seems redundant create a `Device Property` to host the `Location` property. **What is the difference between those two actions?** Just FYI that I cannot find the correct JSON format to report for the `Location` property without it being under `Device Property` neither.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** The correct format to report DateTime is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ (ISO 8601, in UTC). For example, 2018-11-26T8:08:08.808Z.

**Question 2:** There is a known issue for updating a Location property using the Flow connector. We are working on resolving this. Thanks for reporting.